# ¿Cómo crear una tabla de valores a partir de un valor dado en R?

Tags: r

necesito crear una tabla de 22 valores a partir del valor 500, estos valores deben incrementar en 6% cada fila, por ejemplo valor1= 500, valor2= 500x1.06, valor3= valor2x1.06. Existe alguna forma de programarlo, lo intenté pero de una forma muy extensa. Gracias

```
v1=500
v2=v1*1.06
v3=v2*1.06
```

etc... hasta v22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `accumulate` de la librería `purrr` regresa todos los resultados intermedios de la reducción de un vector. En este caso sería los resultados intermedios de un productorio (como una sumatoria, pero con multiplicaciones).

Para usarla defines un vector con largo 22 y el valor 500. No importa que se repita, solo considerará al primer valor y utilizará al largo para limitar la salida. Con `accumulate` le indicas que lo multiplique por 1.06 a lo largo de todos el vector. Automáticamente se aplica de manera recursiva al resultado de la operación anterior.

```
library(tidyverse)

rep(500, 22) -> x   #Vector de largo 22

accumulate(x, ~.x*1.06)  #Hace automáticamente la función recursiva.

 [1]  500.0000  530.0000  561.8000  595.5080  631.2385  669.1128  709.2596  751.8151  796.9240  844.7395
[11]  895.4238  949.1493 1006.0982 1066.4641 1130.4520 1198.2791 1270.1758 1346.3864 1427.1696 1512.7998
[21] 1603.5677 1699.7818
```

Se podría hacer con bucles y quizás con una función recursiva explícita, pero esta es muy simple.

Answer (score 1):

Si analizas la forma de aumentar una cantidad el 6% es equivalente a multiplicarla por 1.06. De este modo el siguiente valor después de 500 es *500x1.06*, el siguiente después de *500x1.06* es *(500x1.06)x1.06=500x(1.06^2)*, el cuarto valor 500x(1.06^3), ... , y el que esta en la posición 22 es 500x(1.06^21). Por lo tanto, puedes obtener el resultado en R base de la siguiente manera

```
500*(1.06^(0:21))
```

Comment: Es una solución menos generalizable a otras operacions que usar `accumulate`. Pero para este caso es muchísimo más eficiente y simple.